# FSCalender Not Showing Events on It?

Tags: ios, swift, events, calendar, fscalendar

How to display events on Fscalender?

This is my code to fetch events from api call.

```
func SetUpUIDashBoardCalenderdata()
{
    APIManager.sharedInstance.FetchParentDashboardCalenderDataFromURL(){(dashBoardCalenderJson)-> Void in
        let calenderVar = JSON(dashBoardCalenderJson)
        print("calenderVar----",calenderVar)
        let info = calenderVar["dates"].rawString()
        let jsonData = info?.data(using: .utf8)!
        let dictionary = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData!, options: [])  as! Array<Any>
        print("dictionary",dictionary)

    }
}
```

Comment: you must have to convert your date response into **yyyy-MM-dd** format.Try this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50020859/selection-color-changes-the-events-color-in-fscalendar/52170654#52170654

Answer (score 0):

You should implement `FSCalendarDataSource` protocol.

please take a look at my example :

```
let events = [Date]()

fileprivate lazy var dateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd"
    return formatter
}()

func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, numberOfEventsFor date: Date) -> Int {
    let dayFormatted = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
    var counter = 0
    for event in events{
        let day = dateFormatter.string(from: event)
        if dayFormatted == day{
            counter += 1
        }
    }
    return counter
}
```

or shorter :

```
func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, numberOfEventsFor date: Date) -> Int {
    let dayFormatted = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
    return events.filter({ dateFormatter.string(from: $0) == dayFormatted }).count
}
```

Comment: i am getting dates in dictionary how to populates those dates on calender.

Comment: Can you add example of your dictionary?

Comment: This Is the response i am getting from the server..   "dates" : [
    "Mon Oct 02 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2017",
    "Wed Oct 04 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2017",
    "Sat Oct 07 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2017",
    "Sun Oct 08 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2017",
    "Mon Oct 09 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2017",
    "Wed Oct 18 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2017",
    "Thu Oct 19 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2017",
    "Fri Oct 20 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2017",
    "Mon Oct 23 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2017",
    "Tue Oct 24 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2017",  ],
  "status" : 1,
  "message" : "Details fetched successfully."
}

Comment: @kishore This is not what you asked for in your question. 
You asked how to display events in `Fscalender`.
btw `dictionary["dates"]` is your array of dates

Comment: sorry for the delay reply since 10 days i was in leave.

Comment: i used your methods but its not getting call.